# Issue with WebMoney Payment Gateway Integration

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I am facing issue with integration of the WebMoney payment gateway into my WordPress website.

The WebMoney payment gateway does not appear during the checkout process on my website. Despite enabling the gateway and configuring the necessary settings correctly, customers are unable to see the WebMoney option as a payment method when they proceed to checkout.

I have thoroughly reviewed the configuration settings and ensured that the plugin is installed and activated correctly. However, the issue persists, and I am unable to identify the root cause of the problem.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Maybe because you are using new Checkout Block instead of Checkout Classic Shortcode and WebMoney Payment Gateway is maybe not compatible with Checkout Block...